# TestNg not executes @BeforeGroup if the method is in another class

Tags: selenium, java, testng

My code structure is like this:

I have four classes having ten tests and one `@BeforeClass` method to run before any of the tests. In each of four classes all tests are of one single group.

And I have one another class which I need to run before that `@BeforeClass` method in four of the tests.

How do I achieve that? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below case, it executes both `@BeforeGroups` and `@BeforeClass`.

First create a base class name `="TestNGBase"` add all `@after/@Before` methods here (including `@BeforeClass,@BeforeGroups` etc..)

And extend this class on all your main test class.

Example:

```
public class TestNGBase {
    boolean logToStandardOut = true;

    @BeforeSuite()
    public void beforeSuite() {
        Reporter.log("--------        @BeforeSuite", logToStandardOut);
    }

    @BeforeGroups(groups = "regression_test")
    public void beforeGroups() {
        Reporter.log("--------        @BeforeGroups", logToStandardOut);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        Reporter.log("--------        @BeforeClass", logToStandardOut);
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        Reporter.log("--------        @BeforeTest", logToStandardOut);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        Reporter.log("--------        @BeforeMethod", logToStandardOut);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        Reporter.log("--------        @AfterMethod", logToStandardOut);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        Reporter.log("--------        @AfterTest", logToStandardOut);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        Reporter.log("--------        @AfterClass", logToStandardOut);
    }

    @AfterGroups(groups = "regression_test")
    public void afterGroups() {
        Reporter.log("--------        @AfterGroups", logToStandardOut);
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite() {
        Reporter.log("--------        @afterSuite", logToStandardOut);
    }
}
```

Create new TestNGXml Class for **Test Case 01**:

```
public class TestNGxml_TS001 extends TestNGBase {
    boolean logToStandardOut = true;

    @Test(groups = { "regression_test" }, priority = 1)
    public void test001() {
        Reporter.log("test001", true);
    }

    @Test(groups = { "regression_test" })
    public void test002() {
        Reporter.log("test002", true);
    }

    @Test(groups = { "regression_test" })
    public void test003() {
        Reporter.log("test003", true);
    }

    @Test(groups = { "regression_test" })
    public void test004() {
        Reporter.log("test004", true);
    }

    @Test(alwaysRun = true)
    public void test005() {
        Reporter.log("test005 - always run = true", true);
    }

}
```

TestNGXml Class for **Test Case 02**:

```
public class TestNGxml_TS002 extends TestNGBase {
    boolean logToStandardOut = true;

    @Test(groups = { "regression_test" })
    public void test201() {
        Reporter.log("test102", true);
    }

    @Test(groups = { "regression_test" })
    public void test202() {
        Reporter.log("test202", true);
    }

    @Test(groups = { "regression_test" })
    public void test203() {
        Reporter.log("test203", true);
    }

    @Test(groups = { "regression_test" })
    public void test204() {
        Reporter.log("test204", true);
    }

}
```

and add a **testng.xml** file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="testngsuite" verbose="1">
    <test name="testCase002">
        <classes>
            <class name="testngxml.TestNGxml_TS001" />
            <class name="testngxml.TestNGxml_TS002" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The **output** would looks like this when we execute `testng.xml` file:

```
--------        @BeforeSuite
--------        @BeforeTest
--------        @BeforeClass
--------        @BeforeGroups
--------        @BeforeMethod
test002
--------        @AfterMethod
--------        @BeforeMethod
test003
--------        @AfterMethod
--------        @BeforeMethod
test004
--------        @AfterMethod
--------        @BeforeMethod
test005 - always run = true
--------        @AfterMethod
--------        @BeforeMethod
test001
--------        @AfterMethod
--------        @AfterClass
--------        @BeforeClass
--------        @BeforeMethod
test102
--------        @AfterMethod
--------        @BeforeMethod
test202
--------        @AfterMethod
--------        @BeforeMethod
test203
--------        @AfterMethod
--------        @BeforeMethod
test204
--------        @AfterMethod
--------        @AfterGroups
--------        @AfterClass
--------        @AfterTest
--------        @afterSuite

===============================================
testngsuite
Total tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 2):

> And I have one another class which I need to run before that
>   `@BeforeClass` method in four of the tests.

To achieve this you can try to do this:
Just make all of the four class extend this "AnotherClass" and add `@BeforeClass` annotation in the constructor of this class.

Hope this will help.